# How to reference member variable in the implementation file

Tags: objective-c, interface

I am learning Objective-C and I am trying to split the class definition from the implementation as shown below.
Now in the code I want to reference the both of:

```
NSString *CarMotorCode;
NSString *CarChassisCode;
```

In the implementation file. I attempted to use:

```
self.CarMotorCode;
self.CarChassisCode;
```

But it does not work. Would you please let me know how to reference it.

**Note**: please let me know what is the right naming convention for the variables enclosed inside the brackets in the implementation section? Are they member variables?

**Car2.m**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Car2.h"

@implementation Car2

-(id) initWithMotorValue:(NSString *)motorCode andChassingValue:(NSInteger)ChassisCode {
    self
}

@end
```

**Car2.h**

```
#ifndef Car2_h
#define Car2_h

@interface Car2 : NSObject {
    NSString *CarMotorCode;
    NSString *CarChassisCode;
}

-(id) initWithMotorValue: (NSString *) motorCode andChassingValue: (NSInteger) ChassisCode;
-(void) startCar;
-(void) stopCrar;

@end

#endif /* Car2_h */
```

Comment: you are on the right track but "self.CarMotorCode;" is the wrong syntax. you need; self->CarMotorCode

Comment: @johnelemans would you please let me know the difference between both notation? is it becase we are referencing a private varible?

Comment: The dot notation is syntactic sugar that provides convenient access to a property’s accessor methods. The `->` is used if you need to dereference the ivars of some object. (Note, if using ivars, you can use `self->motorCode`, or you generally can just omit the `self->` part and use `motorCode` directly. But it’s advisable to use properties with the dot syntax, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared instance variables (ivars). To get the “dot syntax”, you need to declare properties. The “dot syntax” is syntactic sugar that makes use of the “accessor methods” that are synthesized for you when you declare a property. (FWIW, it’s advised to not declare ivars manually, anyway, and rather to declare properties and let the compiler synthesize the necessary ivars. See [Programming with Objective-C: Properties Control Access to an Object’s Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW7) and [Practical Memory Management: Use Accessor Methods to Make Memory Management Easier](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW4).)

Thus:

```
@interface Car2: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *motorCode;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *chassisCode;

- (id)initWithMotorCode:(NSString *)motorCode chassisCode:(NSString *)chassisCode;

@end
```

And your `init` method might look like:

```
@implementation Car2

- (id)initWithMotorCode:(NSString *)motorCode chassisCode:(NSString *)chassisCode {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _motorCode = [motorCode copy];
        _chassisCode = [chassisCode copy];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

That will synthesize ivars `_motorCode` and `_chassisCode` for you behind the scenes, but you generally wouldn’t interact directly with them (except in `init` method, in which case you should avoid accessing properties). But in the rest of your instance methods, you could just use the properties `self.motorCode` and `self.chassisCode`.

A few unrelated notes:

- I dropped the `car` prefix in your property names. It seems redundant to include that prefix when dealing with a car object.
- I start my property names with lowercase letter as a matter of convention.
- I changed the `init` method signature to better mirror the property names (e.g. not `initWithMotorValue` but rather `initWithMotorCode`).
- Alternatively, you might use the `strong` memory qualifier rather than `copy`. E.g.

  ```
  @interface Car2: NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *motorCode;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *chassisCode;

  - (id)initWithMotorCode:(NSString *)motorCode chassisCode:(NSString *)chassisCode;
  @end
  ```

  And

  ```
  - (id)initWithMotorCode:(NSString *)motorCode chassisCode:(NSString *)chassisCode {
      if ((self = [super init])) {
          _motorCode = motorCode;
          _chassisCode = chassisCode;
      }
      return self;
  }
  ```

  But we often use `copy` to protect us against someone passing a `NSMutableString` as one of these properties and then mutating it behind our back. But this is up to you.
- You defined `chassisCode` to be a string in your ivar declaration, but as an `NSInteger` in your init method signature. Obviously, if it’s an `NSInteger`, change both accordingly:

  ```
  @interface Car2: NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *motorCode;
  @property (nonatomic) NSInteger chassisCode;

  - (id) initWithMotorCode:(NSString *)motorCode chassisCode:(NSInteger)chassisCode;

  @end
  ```

  and

  ```
  - (id)initWithMotorCode:(NSString *)motorCode chassisCode:(NSInteger)chassisCode {
      if ((self = [super init])) {
          _motorCode = [motorCode copy];
          _chassisCode = chassisCode;
      }
      return self;
  }
  ```
- If you’re wondering why I didn’t use the property accessor methods in the `init` method, please see [Practical Memory Management: Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).